# Find logarithm in cuda

Tags: cuda, logarithm

How do I find logarithm in cuda? I'm looking for a device function.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
logf(x)
__logf(x)
log2f(x)
__log2f(x)
log10f(x)
__log10f(x)
```

Taken from the [CUDA Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#mathematical-functions-appendix) (Appendix D).

Answer (score 0):

As Ade says log* functions. Keep in mind that __log* might be fast but not accurate.